# Using access token that was obtained from AWS cognito to protect Web API calls - Beginner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Finally with the greatest difficulty, I was able to make the user login work. My code is given below. I also got the `Access Token` printed to the console. So it all works fine.

Now, I need to access my `AWS API Gateway` function which is called `saveHospitalInformation` (Also which is accessed from https://awsxxxxxxxx/save-Hospital-Information ). How can I send my `Access Token` that I obtained from the above step to the `AWS API Gateway` function ? Is it in the header ? Can someone show me a code example?

I know that the `Access Token` is only valid for 1 hour. So, incase if it's expired what is the error message that is sent to the client ?

I am new to AWS and Access Tokens so can someone guide me here.

The code that i used for user Sign-in is given below:

```
   // Cognito User Pool Id
AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1: XxxxxxxxxxxXxxxxxxxxxx'
});


var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username111',
    Password : 'password123'
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX',
    ClientId : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username111',
    Pool : userPool
   };
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('22222222 1' );
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
       // alert(err);
       console.log('ERRR IS '+ err );
    },

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the lack of examples for your specific problems. There are many ways to integrate these services, which is why you may not be able to find examples for your specific use case.

Let me try to answer your question in parts:

> How can I send my Access Token that I obtained from the above step to
>   the AWS API Gateway function ? Is it in the header ? Can someone show
>   me a code example?

You currently have 2 options:

1. Use Cognito Federated Identity to generate AWS credentials. See the [Cognito documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) for creating a credentials provider and [API Gateway documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-javascript) for integrating that credentials provider with a generated Javascript SDK.
2. Use an API Gateway [custom authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) to validate the access token yourself. We have [example authorizers](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints) that will validate a JWT generated by Cognito.

In option 1, the token is never sent to API Gateway, only to Cognito Identity. The SDKs should manage the lifecycle of your tokens, fetching a new access token when the current one expires.

In option 2, you are responsible for passing the token to the API. Custom authorizers currently support using a header on the incoming request to pass the token, which you can define when configuring it.

> I know that the Access Token is only valid for 1 hour. So, incase if
>   it's expired what is the error message that is sent to the client ?

This will depend on the option you choose from above.

In option 1, the SDK should handle this for you. If for some reason the session expires, you will receive an error indicating that the user needs to login again.

In option 2, currently the custom authorizers will only return a 403 if you return an error. We are looking to improve this experience, but I cannot commit to a timetable for those updates.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. I have another question which is also related to this. **At times**, despite entering the correct username and password I use to get the error message `NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.`. Is this a bug ? .. Also user login takes a long time. Is this a bug too ?

Comment: @Illep please post details on the Cognito Forums and someone can look into this.

Answer (score 0):

recently I had to deal with OAuth2 authentication but I don't know AWS. In case you're in the same situation, here is an example of HTTP request with a token :
  GET /resource HTTP/1.1
  Host: server.example.com
  Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM

If helpful, more documentation about that [here](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll have a look. Unfortunately, AWS doesn't have a good documentation that explains this nor a support team who could help out. Having sorting most of the problems myself, I am in a good position to write better tutorials than the amazon staff. I am hoping to do so in the next few weeks.